# How do I continously print in order?

Tags: python

```
def maketriangle(num):
    num = input("Enter a number")
    number = int(num)
    for i in range(0, number):
        for j in range(0, i+1):
            print("*", end='')
        print("\n")
print(maketriangle(num))
```

Hello, I'm completely new to Python.
I want to make a function that prints a triangle. 
This code will make a triangle in a pyramid form with "*".

So if I insert 2, it will make a triangle like

```
*  
**
```

And if I insert 4, it will make a triangle like

```
*  
**  
***  
****
```

I want to change `*` as this order: `?!#$`
so if I insert 4, it will make a triangle like

```
?  
?!  
?!#  
?!#$
```

How should I change my code..?

Comment: take a look at `mod` or `%` and string slicing.

Comment: What would the fifth line look like?

Comment: `'?!#$'[0:n]` will give you the first *n* characters of the string.

Comment: @khelwood: `?!#$IndexError` of course.

Comment: @usr2564301 Why not `?!#$?`?

Answer (score 2):

How about this minimalistic function:

```
def make_t(h, ch):
    for i in range(1, h+1):
        print(ch * (i // len(ch)) + ch[:i % len(ch)])
```

Examples:

```
make_t(4, '*')

*
**
***
****
```

---

```
make_t(5, '?!#$')

?
?!
?!#
?!#$
?!#$?
```

To understand how it operates, you need to take a look at *integer division* (`//`), [*moduli*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) (`%`) and *string slicing* (`[:]`).

Comment: thank you!! I never thought of integer division but now I got it!!

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
 def makeT(num):
     lst=['?','!','#','$']
     for i in range(0,num):
         for j,k in zip(range(0,i+1),lst):
             print(k, end='')
         print("\n")
```

Comment: instead of using `lst` in `zip`, use `itertools.cycle(lst)`. It will allow you to print the pattern again from start for `num` greater than `len(lst)`